# Web landing page is not connected to HTTPS

Tags: laravel, https

I have a problem, my website is running on Laravel 5, I have set up SSL cert and configured it using Load Balancer in AWS. Set up listeners for HTTP(80) and HTTPS(443). SSL checker seems fine. I can access https://www.mydomainname.com and it directs to a secure page.

However everytime I enter [www.mydomainname.com](http://www.mydomainname.com) on any browser it leads to a not secure page, when I navigate to another page like mydomainname.com/business its secured.

My AppServiceProvider conf:

```
public function boot()
    {
      if($this->app->environment('production')) {
         \URL::forceScheme('https');
     }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you need to configure from `.htaccess` as well for 302 redirect

Comment: You can refer this guide to set a load balancer based redirection
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/

Answer (score 1):

`\URL::forceScheme('https');` will not redirect to https, it is used to build links with https inside app.

If you want redirect in Laravel you can use middleware:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
  if (!$request->secure()) {
    return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri());
  }
  return $next($request);
}
```

Of course, the best way is to use redirect with apache/nginx.